# Ruby Rails .inject equivalent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby

I'm very new in Node.js from Ruby Rails and although I'm using it for just a few weeks, I'm a bit confident about the basics.

However, I'm trying to convert a specific hash that uses `inject` in Ruby Rails. I'm not quite sure how to convert this in Javascript.

Can anyone help?

This is my Ruby Rails code:

```
result = CurrencyExchangeRates.all.inject({}) do |rates, c|
  rates[c.currency] = c.rate
  rates
end

# => {"one"=>"one", "two"=>"two", "three"=>"three"}
```

How can I do this correctly in Node.js

I'm looking at `.forEach` however I think this is just for arrays.

```
currency_exchange_rates.forEach(element => {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
 const reducer = (rates, c) => Object.assign(rates, { [c.currency]: c.rate } )
 const result = all_rates.reduce(reducer, {})
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me read up on this! Will accept your answer after checking! Appreciate pointing me where to read the equivalent!

Comment: Thank you so much! Definitely what I needed!